# node mongodb not keeping zero-filled data

Tags: mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I'm following this guide as a basis for keeping analytic data:
[pre-aggregated-reports](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/)

My code is generating an update object {} that looks as follows (actual example):

```
{ '$inc': {},
  '$set':
   { 'hourly.9': { total: 0, global: 0, trends: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] },
     'minute.9.51': { total: 0, global: 0 },
     'minute.9.52': { total: 0, global: 0 },
     'minute.9.53': { total: 0, global: 0 },
     'minute.9.54': { total: 0, global: 0 },
     'minute.9.55': { total: 0, global: 0 },
     'minute.9.56': { total: 0, global: 0 },
     'minute.9.57': { total: 0, global: 0 },
     'minute.9.58': { total: 0, global: 0 },
     'minute.9.59': { total: 0, global: 0 },
     'hourly.10': { total: 0, global: 0, trends: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] },
     'hourly.11': { total: 0, global: 0, trends: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] },
     'hourly.12': { total: 0, global: 0, trends: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] },
     'hourly.13': { total: 0, global: 0, trends: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] },
     'hourly.14': { total: 0, global: 0, trends: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] },
     'hourly.15': { total: 0, global: 0, trends: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] },
     'hourly.16': { total: 0, global: 0, trends: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] },
     'hourly.17': { total: 0, global: 0, trends: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] },
     'hourly.18': { total: 0, global: 0, trends: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] },
     'hourly.19': { total: 0, global: 0, trends: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] },
     'hourly.20': { total: 0, global: 0, trends: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] },
     'hourly.21': { total: 0, global: 0, trends: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] },
     'hourly.22': { total: 0, global: 0, trends: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] },
     'hourly.23': { total: 0, global: 0, trends: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] } },
  '$addToSet': {}
}
```

And the update code looks like this:

```
daily.update(query, update, {upsert:true, safe:true}, function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
        console.log("error writing update. " + err);
        throw err;
    }
});
```

query is a simple object {'_id': someid}, the update is the object listed above.  The document is created but none of the zero filled fields are stored.

```
{
    "_id" : "20140804/example.com/13567219",
    "metadata" : {
        "date" : ISODate("2014-08-04T04:00:00Z"),
        "host" : "example.com",
        "id" : "13567219"
    }
}
```

However if I run the same upsert in the mongo console, the record is created/updated with all the zero filled fields in place:

```
    "13" : {
        "total" : 0,
        "global" : 0,
        "trends" : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    },
    "14" : {
        "total" : 0,
        "global" : 0,
        "trends" : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    },
    ...
    ...
    "22" : {
        "total" : 0,
        "global" : 0,
        "trends" : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    },
    "23" : {
        "total" : 0,
        "global" : 0,
        "trends" : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    },
    "9" : {
        "total" : 0,
        "global" : 0,
        "trends" : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    }
},
"metadata" : {
    "date" : ISODate("2014-08-04T04:00:00Z"),
    "host" : "example.com",
    "id" : "13560169"
},
"minute" : {
    "9" : {
        "51" : {
                "total" : 0,
                "global" : 0
        },
        "52" : {
                "total" : 0,
                "global" : 0
        },
        "53" : {
                "total" : 0,
                "global" : 0
        },
        "54" : {
                "total" : 0,
                "global" : 0
        },
        "55" : {
                "total" : 0,
                "global" : 0
        },
        "56" : {
                "total" : 0,
                "global" : 0
        },
        "57" : {
                "total" : 0,
                "global" : 0
        },
        "58" : {
                "total" : 0,
                "global" : 0
        },
        "59" : {
                "total" : 0,
                "global" : 0
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a setting that I'm missing on the native driver to make it force populating the data?

Comment: Can you tell us more information about the version you are using? I am using MongoDB 2.6.3 and node driver 1.4.2 without any issue.

Comment: I'm using Mongo version 2.4.10 and (mongodb) driver version 1.4.7

Comment: I upgraded mongo to 2.6.3 and still same issue.  Had to clear up my update a little since I had some sloppy code that had $set: {} even when not setting things (ie, just doing $inc's).  But still not getting the pre-allocated document saved with zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were/are no issues on versions of Mongo or the native driver.  The issue was PLBKAC - Problem Lies Between Keyboard And Chair.

Within my code (running on node) I had the update outside of the lookup of a document.  So the updates were taking place before the document returned from the DB...all that lovely async goodness.

Moving the update method inside of the document lookup fixed the issue of the update not pre-allocating the document.

I had this:

```
...
... code that updates the update object with $inc's, and $addToSets...
...

daily.find({'_id' : id}, {}, {'limit': 1}).toArray(function(err, doc) {
    ...
    ...
});

daily.update(query, update, {upsert:true, safe:true}, function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
        console.log("error writing update. " + err);
        throw err;
    }
});
```

and moved the daily.update inside of the daily.find...

```
daily.find({'_id' : id}, {}, {'limit': 1}).toArray(function(err, doc) {
    ...
    ...

    daily.update(query, update, {upsert:true, safe:true}, function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("error writing update. " + err);
            throw err;
        }
    });
});
```

So future people, make sure all of your edits to the update object are async safe :)